# exif_read_data - Incorrect APP1 Exif Identifier Code

Tags: php, image, exif

I have problem with some of my photos when i want to read EXIF data.

My code below:

```
$exif_date = exif_read_data($file_path,  'IFD0');
```

With some images i get warrning:
Message: exif_read_data(001.jpg) [function.exif-read-data]: Incorrect APP1 Exif Identifier Code

My question is: how can I awoid this warrning, can I check somehow if app1 is correct before exif_read?
Thanks for help.

Comment: I still don't know why i have this warrning, so I found the only way to get rid of it is to put "@" before exif_read_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP's `getimagesize()` function to extract the APP markers from the file and then verify if the APP1 marker actually contains EXIF data (the content for that marker should start with 'Exif')

Answer (score 19):

For the quick answer, take a look at the last rows of this post.

I think some code is still missing. I came exactly across the same problem and after searching I found multiple websites related to this problem:

http://drupal.org/node/556970
a bug report with 2 solutions:

1. simply put an `@` in front of `exif_read_data`
2. check `$imageinfo['APP1']` if it contains Exif

After reading dcro's answer here, I found out that the second parameter of [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) returns such an `$imageinfo` array. Now I tested one of my images with the following code:

```
<?php
getimagesize("test.jpg", $info);
var_dump($info);
?>
```

This returned the following:

```
array(1) {
  ["APP1"]=>
  string(434) "http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/<?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Exempi + XMP Core 4.1.1">
 <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
   <dc:type>Image</dc:type>
   <dc:format>image/jpeg</dc:format>
  </rdf:Description>
 </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>

<?xpacket end="w"?>"
}
```

This btw. doesn't look like Exif. This looks more like [XMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform), but the funny part is that for example the exiftool finds some exif data (orientation for example). In the [XMP specification](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/xmp/pdfs/XMPSpecificationPart3.pdf) I found that it is possible to have XMP and Exif data side by side in one file (page 18). Further search revealed that there are script like this one to [extract Exif from XMP](http://photography-on-the.net/ee/beta/cs_xmp_to_exif.php).

Anyway, since

1. getimagesize() does not give me usable information about the Exif in my picture and
2. the stated script shows that in my image the Exif data is not embedded into the XMP data and
3. it simply works to suppress the exif-read-data() warning

I will still use the `@exif-read-data($file_path)` solution.

Comment: there is also a [getimagesizefromstring()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php) in case you are reading image data returned from a database blob as string